# How to choose the correct child element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the next html code:

```
<fieldset id="q1">
  <legend>Quest 1</legend>
  <div class="a1">
    <label for="q2a1">Some text 1</label>
    <select id="q2a1" name="q2a1">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="a2">
    <select id="q2a2" name="q2a2">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <label for="q2a2">Some text 2</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The basic idea: the sum of the two selectors must be equal to 2.

Example: If I choose the in the first selector number 2, the second selector must be avaible 
the 0 only. If I choose in the first selector number 1, the second selector must 
must have only 1. And vice versa. 
As you can see the tag `label` can be located before and after `select`.
I started writing code, but it stuck on choosing a necessary child. 
Also likely not be able to use elements by the `id`, because the form a very large.

js:

```
$('select').change(function(event) {
  var c;
  c = 3 - $(this).val();
  options = '';
  for (var i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
  }
        alert($(this).parent().parent().html());
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to look for the element, you can simply use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2), and jQuery does the hard work for you:

```
$('select').bind('change keyup click', function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var $other = $this.closest('fieldset').find('select').not(this);
   var selectedValue = parseInt($this.val(), 10);
   $other.val(2 - selectedValue);
});
```

I've added the `keyup` and `click` events so it plays nicely with the mouse and keyboard.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7TX86/1